# WPF. Animation of window transparency

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, window, transparency

I need a smooth animation of window transparency. I added this code to the "LOADED" event of the window.

```
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            myDoubleAnimation.From = 100.0;
            myDoubleAnimation.To = 0.1;
            myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
            Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
            myStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

There is a sharp jump of transparency. Animation is missing. Where there has been a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity is a relative value in the range `0 .. 1`. Use

```
myDoubleAnimation.From = 1.0;
```

or don't set it at all.

Instead of using a Storyboard, you may also just write

```
BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, new DoubleAnimation
{
    To = 0.1,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
});
```

Comment: That's what the server wrote to me. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."